Can I post partial code for review?
I have code which relies on my class internal structure and some API/libraries.
Can I post only the point of interest code if used class internals, API and libraries and not critical for the code understanding and not subject of code review?
My particular example is render method of a large class which uses some internal data to render and wrappers for GDI/GDI+ functions which are not point of interest.
If I try to post every definition of members/types/functions used in the code, this cascades to posting too large portion of code which is hard to cut/read.
So, to put in a nutshell, what is the rule of thumb to cut the unnecessary code? Would "keep only parts strongly necessary for understanding" work?

We don't have a clear line. Try your best to post code which makes sense. I personally am used to Python which uses duck typing so don't feel much context is needed. However others sometimes disagree. I've had someone tell me on my alt my self-contained question which had an import and a subclass was a violation of our sites rules... If someone gives you grief feel free to ping me to have a look over.

I have closed your question as I feel our existing posts have already addressed the issue enough times. If you feel the linked posts don't answer the question and so I shouldn't hammer the question closed please let me know.

@Peilonrayz, thank you for the links and input. I don't mind the question to be closed, but the linked questions doesn't cover one thing (actually not explicitly stated in my question). I want the render method to be reviewed but I can't upload all project to some public repo because of NDA. I am quite sure any developer would be able to understand and review the code without these other parts. So, the question is how to behave in this case.

From a legal perspective you probably shouldn't post NDA code on Code Review. If the section you're posting isn't under NDA (hence the divide) then I've liked 200_success's answer on how do deal with confidentiality (edited into the close list now too). The answer in short basically suggests passing off a porn store as a clothing store. Your situation is a little more complicated, and without all the information at had I can't really say what to do. If asked what something is then providing a non-NDA edit probably would work. But hard to say.

If you're posting a portion of your code, it's very helpful to provide something that exercises your extract.  Not only does this help us understand the inputs and expected outputs, but if it's compilable and runnable then it can facilitate trying out possible modifications. The driving code might be your unit tests (probably worthy of review in their own right) or a short wrapper program that constructs suitable inputs and provides fake objects for the lower layer.  If you don't want the harness code reviewed, it's normal to blockquote it with >      to show that it's just illustrative.

@TobySpeight, thanks for the input. Even though I realized that the best way would be to move all the related code to a separate petty application to make the code review more focused on my concerns, I still have a key question. In case of generic code I could post it on godbolt, but when it comes win Windows application with extensive use of GDI+, this won't run/compile on the godbolt. So the question is where to post the whole code if I still need only 20% of it for the code review?
